# Why is my batch showing error in test class but not in actual execution?

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch that has a callout and it goes something like this.

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<Connection__c>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
    protected List<Response__c> resList;

    public MyBatch() {
        this.resList = new List<Response__c>();
    }

    public List<Connection> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return [SELECT Id, External_System__c FROM Connection__c];
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Connection__c> scope) {
        for (Connection__c con : scope) {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:MyCreds/somepath?type=' + con.External_System__c);
            request.setMethod('GET');

            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

            String body = response.getBody();

            Response__c res = new Response__c();
            res.JSON = body;

            this.resList.add(res);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        if (this.resList.size() > 0) {
            Database.insert(this.resList, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the batch is executed successfully when you call it in another class or even in the anonymous window like this.

```
MyBatch b = new MyBatch();
Database.executeBatch(b, 5);
```

But, when I created a test class and try to run the test. It's throwing an error **"FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: A callout was unsuccessful because of pending uncommitted work related to a process, flow, or Apex operation. Commit or roll back the work, and then try again."**

My test class goes something like this:

```
@IsTest
public with sharing class RetrieveClipboardDataBatchTest {

    @TestSetup
    public static void setup() {
        Connection__c esc = new Connection__c();
        esc.External_System__c = 'Activities';
        insert esc;
    }

    @IsTest
    public static void testBatchActivities() {
        Connection__c esc = [SELECT Id FROM Connection__c WHERE External_System__c = 'Clipboard'];

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpActivityResponse());
        MyBatch b = new MyBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(b, 5);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    public class MockHttpActivityResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"data": [{"name": "Book Club","archived": false,"hexColor": "eb7676","archivedByUserId": null,"archivedTimestamp": null}]}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is pointing to these lines of code:

```
if (this.resList.size() > 0) {
   Database.insert(this.resList, false);
}
```

I don't understand why, because the DML is in the finish method and the callout is in the execute method which, as I understand, should be in different transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be one of two things, and I'm not entirely sure which is correct.

- Calling `Database.executeBatch();` is a DML-like operation (it creates an `AsyncApexJob` record and returns the Id to you)
- The DML in your `@TestSetup` method counts as DML in the test when your `execute()` method is actually run

The magic of `Test.stopTest()` makes it so that async apex is run as part of the test method itself (as part of this method call, or maybe after the call but before the next statement). So if you are performing DML (or a DML-like operation) in the same "transaction" as when `execute()` is running, Salesforce will complain.

If the issue is the calling of `Database.executeBatch()`, then the solution here is to call your `execute()` method directly (inside of `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`).

If the issue is the `@TestSetup` method, then the solution is to use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` to wrap the DML that you're performing in your `@TestSetup` method. While we can only use startTest/stopTest once per test method, we can additionally use it in a `@TestSetup` method (and this is a nifty trick to avoid running into governor limits in test classes that require a lot of setup).

Even if the issue is the DML in the `@TestSetup` method, I'd still recommend calling your `execute()` method directly instead of going through `Database.executeBatch()` because you're testing *your code* and not testing that `Database.executeBatch()` is calling your code (that's something we should trust that Salesforce themselves test).

Comment: I've tried calling execute directly in my test method, but it is still throwing an error. Isn't finish method a different transaction?

Comment: @CarlOrtiz, if you call execute() directly from your test, how can you get an error in the finish() method? (Yes, finish() is a different transaction.) In any case, contrary to Derek's answer I don't believe the problem being in anything you presented in your question. Do you have any triggers/flows launching when you insert Response__c?

Comment: @FelixvanHove Because I also manually called the finish method. I have codes in the finish method that needed to be tested as well.